# Cannot deploy LWR Enhanced site to scratch org: site template requires a route of type service-not-available

Tags: digital-experience, lwr

I created a new digital community based on the `B2B Commerce (LWR)` template. When I deploy it to a scratch org using ExperienceBundle Metadata API, I get this error:

> The current site template requires a route of type service-not-available, but none was found. Make sure all template routes are present in the site.

I could not find anything useful in the docs about how to enable SNA page, except this [snippet](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_sna_page.htm&type=5):

> This feature is available for most sites that use Salesforce’s CDN for Digital Experiences. The Salesforce CDN is enabled by default for sites that use enhanced domains. You can also configure custom domains to use the Salesforce CDN option.

Does it mean that in order to enable SNA page for an LWR Digital Experience site, CDN should be enabled? Or how can I deploy the digital experience using SFDX?